# Como buscar um valor do json da API do goo.gl para C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

Estou a tentar usar a API do goo.gl para encurtar alguns link. O problema é que não sei como tiro a URL gerada do json de retorno. Veja em baixo como é organizado:

```
{
 "kind": "urlshortener#url",
 "id": "AQUI VEM A URL DO GOOGLE",
 "longUrl": "http://url-dos-detalhes/"
}
```

e eu preciso de sacar só o **id** do `json` no meu *controller* usando C#. Estou a usar o conceito MVC, em ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem, é só dar um `deserialize` usando um tipo `dynamic` :

```
 using Newtonsoft.Json;

 var output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>("{ \"kind\": \"urlshortener#url\", \"id\": \"AQUI VEM A URL DO GOOGLE\", \"longUrl\": \"http://url-dos-detalhes/\"}");
 Console.WriteLine(output.id);
```

Comment: fiz parecido, mas com o JsonObject. muito boa essa biblioteca

Answer (score 1):

A Google possui o pacote [Google.Apis.Urlshortener](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Urlshortener.v1/). Basta instalar o mesmo via NuGet e utilizá-lo.

Para instalar, digite o seguinte comando no **Package Manager Console**:

> Install-Package Google.Apis.Urlshortener.v1

Após isso, basta utilizar a API desta forma:

```
UrlshortenerService service = new UrlshortenerService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
{
      ApiKey = "SUA API KEY AQUI"
});

var url = "www.google.com";
Url response = service.Url.Insert(new Url { LongUrl = url }).Execute();

var id = response.Id;
```